# How to disable anti-spam in Outlook 2007 for specific account?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2007, spam-prevention, pop3

I don't want email received via one of my Outlook POP3 accounts to be put in the spam folder.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Actions->Junk E-mail->Junk E-mail Options, on the Safe Recipients tab you can specify the account you want to not be spam-filtered and then messages sent to that account should never be flagged as spam and your rules can run on those messages.

Edit: Sorry, my mistake, it doesn't allow you to enter your own address... But if you right-click the message that was moved into the Junk folder and select Junk E-mail->Add recipient to safe recipients list then it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for tip! Indeed my account receives a lot of messages from different addresses so I want to disable spam-filter for all emails to it.

Comment: Please note that what I was saying was to add the receiving address as a safe recipient, meaning your own address. So all email sent to your address, regardless of where they are coming from, will be treated as non-spam.

Comment: Unfortunately Office Outlook 2008 doesn't allow to add own address saying that this will switch off the spam filter. What exactly I need

Comment: Well, your question title says Outlook 2007...
In 2007 if you do like I said in my edit, it works. I know nothing about 2008 :-)